# How to start chat on answer for question

Tags: support, chat

When someone posts an answer to a question, sometimes there is a lot to talk about. I know that there is a way to start chats, but I don't know how. If it matters, I had 155 reputation when I posted this question.

Comment: There's an automatic offer by the system after a certain number of comments to continue in chat. There's nothing you need to do other than click on the link and then continue in chat

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the quick response. Recently I was helping someone through the comments, and we had around 20 comments, I am pretty sure I would have seen that option if it appeared. Maybe I missed it? After how long or how many comments will it appear?

Comment: I assume it's the same as the auto mod flag [20 comments in 3 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387905/whats-the-standard-for-which-comments-on-meta-stack-overflow-are-moved-to-chat)

Comment: It is only triggered if there only two commenters and on the 5th (?) back-and-forth.

Comment: I think the amount of commenters is actually relevant. E.g. if only 2 users are back-and-forthing, the message will be shown earlier than >2 users are posting comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're wanting to control the process, just [create a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new) directly and link to it in comments. That's all the automatic process does. It's still up to people to join the chat if they so desire.

Alternatively, if they are in chat already, you can always join a room they are in and see if they are willing to converse (provided the room rules allow it). Just be prepared to have the room ask you to take your conversation outside that room.

Comment: What you don't want to read in chat: *Get a room* ...

Comment: Note that you need [100 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) to be able to create chat rooms.